# Remove string in between two other strings

Tags: python-3.x, string, python-re

I have a string that I need to remove the characters in the string between two other strings.

At the moment I have the following code, I'm not too sure why it doesn't work.

```
def removeYoutube(itemDescription):
    itemDescription = re.sub('<iframe>.*</iframe>','',desc,flags=re.DOTALL)
    return itemDescription
```

It doesn't remove the string in between and including  and .

Example Input (String):

`"<div style="text-align: center;"><iframe allowfullscreen="frameborder=0" height="350" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/EKaUJExxmEA" width="650"></iframe></div>"`

Expected Output: `<div style="text-align: center;"></div>`

As you can see from the output it should remove all of the parts containing `<iframe></iframe>`.

Comment: In general you get better answers if you provide sample input and the expected output as it reduced ambiguity.

Comment: There is no pattern `<iframe>` in the input. Only `<iframe `.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `BeautifulSoup` not `regex`, as `regex` is a poor choice for parsing a `HTML`. [Here's why](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/590747/using-regular-expressions-to-parse-html-why-not).

Here's how:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

sample = """
<div style="text-align: center;"><iframe allowfullscreen="frameborder=0" height="350" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/EKaUJExxmEA" width="650"></iframe></div>
"""

s = BeautifulSoup(sample, "html.parser")

for tag in s.find_all(True):
    if tag.name == "iframe":
        tag.extract()
print(s)
```

Output:

```
<div style="text-align: center;"></div>
```

Comment: thanks for the answer I don't know why I didn't think of that and thanks for linking the page as to why. Will be using this more in the future than using regex. Much appreciated :)